# Find the total number of working days in between two days, excluding holidays

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have two dates, for example:

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
```

Now considering I have a holiday `tomorrow`, how to find out the total number of working days. Working days are the days excluding `saturday and sunday`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `datetime` module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
end_day = 30

bDays = sum(1 for day in range(1, end_day + 1) if (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=day)).weekday() not in [5, 6] )    
print(bDays)
```

**Output:**

```
22
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

start_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
holidays = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)]

print(np.busday_count(start_date, end_date, holidays=holidays))
```